# Semantic UI star rating and Angularjs ngRepeat combined not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, semantic-ui, rating

I have the following code

```
...
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="s in stats">
      ...
      <td>
          {{s.status}}
      </td>
      <td>
          <div class="ui star rating" data-rating="{{ s.rating }}" data-max-rating="5"></div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
....
```

I have the JS added to the controller as well

```
$('.rating')
    .rating();
```

but I have not been able to get the star rating inside table cell to work. If I replace the "td" tag with "div" I can see the rating stars, but of course it'll be misplaced. Do I need to add any additional tag/directive/script to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't find a solution, you could try to use [Angular1 Star Rating](https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular1-star-rating). I already used it and can affirm you that it works fine with your scenario: table, ng-repeat, data from an object. There is the rating from [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#rating) too, but I haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when i included `script tag of rating` in every  `ng-repeat`

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in hotels.data" >
      <script> $(".rating").rating();</script>
  ...
```